# Dynamically add and run a vba code

Tags: vba, excel, macros, export-to-csv

The followings are my current steps

1. Access file exports a CSV file by Macro (VBA code)
2. The exported CSV file get modified by Macro (VBA code)

Right now, I'm executing the macro on Access (step 1)-> under the exported file, add the code and run (step 2)

I'd like to simplify the process.

Is it possible to by doing step 1, the step 2 code get added to the csv file and run?

Step 1 code

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim intFile As Integer
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim strHold    
strFilePath = "C:\temp\TEST.csv"    
Set dbs = CurrentDb    
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("Import", dbOpenForwardOnly)    
intFile = FreeFile
Open strFilePath For Output As #intFile    
Do Until rst.EOF
   For intCount = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
   strHold = strHold & rst(intCount).Value & "|"
   Next
   If Right(strHold, 1) = "|" Then
      strHold = Left(strHold, Len(strHold) - 1)
   End If
   Print #intFile, strHold
   rst.MoveNext
   strHold = vbNullString
Loop    
Close intFile    
rst.Close    
Set rst = Nothing        
End Function
```

Step 2 code

```
Sub deleterows()
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
For i = lastrow To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 4).Value < Date Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next i
End Sub
```

*note* I prefer not to use windows scheduler to run Macro at a certain time.

My good reference has been so far [Is it possible to automatically input VBA code when a new sheet is generated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450440/is-it-possible-to-automatically-input-vba-code-when-a-new-sheet-is-generated) & [Dynamically insert macro into a new excel workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635231/dynamically-insert-macro-into-a-new-excel-workbook) & https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/219905

I will try my best to be responsive! Please leave a comment for clarification. Thank you!

Comment: (a) You can't have VBA in a CSV file - a CSV file is a simple text file.  (b) Instead of deleting rows via a macro, why don't you just not bother writing those records to the original CSV file?  (c) I just noticed that your file isn't a CSV file anyway, it's a pipe-delimited file with a CSV extension.

Comment: @YowE3K thanks for the comment! Since It's a SQL server that is connected with Access, It's impossible for me to edit it.

Comment: So you can't edit "Step 1" code?  It isn't Access VBA?

Comment: @YowE3K to follow-up (a), I believe I can run a vba code on the csv file. As I have deleted unnecessary rows through vba code.

Comment: @YowE3K Maybe I can code to export only those rows that I want to export?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132334/discussion-between-john-tipton-and-yowe3k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply change your existing Step 1 code to be:

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim intFile As Integer
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim strHold    
strFilePath = "C:\temp\TEST.csv"    
Set dbs = CurrentDb    
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("Import", dbOpenForwardOnly)    
intFile = FreeFile
Open strFilePath For Output As #intFile    
Do Until rst.EOF
   'Check the 4th field to see whether it is today or later
   If CDate(rst(3)) >= Date Then
       'If so, create a record (if not, don't)
       For intCount = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
           strHold = strHold & rst(intCount).Value & "|"
       Next
       If Right(strHold, 1) = "|" Then
           strHold = Left(strHold, Len(strHold) - 1)
       End If
       Print #intFile, strHold
   End If
   rst.MoveNext
   strHold = vbNullString
Loop    
Close intFile    
rst.Close    
Set rst = Nothing        
End Function
```

Comment: So you have edited to CDate(rst(3)) >= Date! I see what you are doing there! Thanks will let you know how it works!

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a genius! :) You found a much simpler way to solve it! Thank you again

Comment: Just check whether the downstream processes are expecting comma or pipe as the delimiter.  My guess is that your old method was saving the file out of excel as a true comma-separated values file, while Access was saving it as pipe-delimited.  (You may need to change the `"|"` to `","` in the code I posted.)